# Object variable or with block variable not set error vb.net

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I am populating combo box from database. In debug i can see that the combo box has been populated .

here is the code

```
Private Sub ComboID_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboID.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim data(21) As String
        Try
            t_code.Text = ComboID.SelectedItem(0)
            ComboID.Visible = False
            data = getData(t_code.Text)

            populateFields(data)


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

but when i run this program i get error:Object variable or with block variable not set error

i would really appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: The error is likely in the getdata or populateFields functions.  Please post those as well

Comment: i didn't program them ..i just used the databindings in the properties..and the combobox is populated when i run the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just knowing that the combobox is populated is not enough. You should still be testing for

`SelectedIndex >= 0`

It is possible that SelectedIndex is changing to -1 if the user clears the selection.

Of course, it is also quite likely that getData is returning Nothing and populateFields can't handle that. It would probably throw a

```
If data isNot Nothing
end if
```

test around the populateFields call, too. It never hurts to test for edge cases.